# How to draw a trend line that joins the highest point of every candle after first hour of day

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I want to write an EA that joins the highest points of each candle using a trend line (after the first hour of a day). I saw the [documentation for the trend line](https://docs.mql4.com/constants/objectconstants/enum_object/obj_trend).

This is what I've done:

```
ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_TREND,sub_window,time1,price1,time2,price2)

ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clr);
ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_STYLE,style);
ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_WIDTH,width);
ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_RAY,false);
```

I know I am suppose to iterate through the highest value for each candle and get it's time, but I'm not sure how to go about this. How can this be done?

This image shows what I am trying to do

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried this but it's not displaying the line. Also how can I specifically limit the trend line to join candles that appear after the first hour of the day?

```
void CalculateTrendLine()  {
   for(int i=0;i<30;i++){

   if (iTime(_Symbol,60,i) > 1) {
   ObjectCreate(0,"TLine"+i,OBJ_TREND,0, iTime(_Symbol,0,i), iHigh(_Symbol,0,i), iTime(_Symbol,0,i+1), iHigh(_Symbol,0,i+1));


   printf("trend start", iHigh( _Symbol,0,i));
  printf("trend end", iHigh( _Symbol,0,i+1));

  ObjectSetInteger(0,"TLine"+i,OBJPROP_COLOR,clrMagenta);
  ObjectSetInteger(0,"TLine"+i,OBJPROP_STYLE,STYLE_SOLID);
  ObjectSetInteger(0,"TLine"+i,OBJPROP_RAY,false); 

   }
```

}
}

Comment: you should loop over all the candles (as much as you need) and check whether it is not the first hour of the day (or any other conditions you may need later). `iTime(_Symbol,0,i)` gives you time of the `i`-th candle (`0`-current) and `iHigh(_Symbol,0,i)` gives high of the candle.

Comment: @DanielKniaz I just updated the question

Comment: ok, and did you tried to see the problem? of course this wont work because of `i>20` in loop condition

Comment: @DanielKniaz Oops, missed that. After correcting it, it still didn't display the trend lines

Comment: @DanielKniaz also how would I limit the time frame?

Comment: name of the object is "OTrend" which is incorrect of course because same name is used for each object, MT4 replaces the object in such case. Try to add `Print()` lines to see what is the problem. No idea what do you mean by timeframe, second parameter in `iTime` and other similar function is your timeframe, 0 means current one but you can put any value of out `ENUM_TIMEFRAMES` values.

Comment: @DanielKniaz I changed the object names, so now they are unique. Now I am getting horizontal lines that appear for a few seconds and disappear instead of the lines joining the highest point of each candle. I am calling `CalculateTrendLine()` in `OnTick()`.  When I said the time frame I was referring to specifically calculating or the condition to make sure trend lines on candles are drawn after the first hour.

Comment: please show/update your code, and add `Print()` for yourself to see what is going on. You can call `iTime(_Symbol,60,i)` to see `PERIOD_H1` candles and then make sure time is > 1:00 am. Time is simply integer (number of seconds past 01.01.1970) so you can do any kind of manipulations with it or simply call `TimeHour(datime time)` to get number of the current hour (from 0 to 23)

Comment: @DanielKniaz I've updated the question with my latest code. The trend lines don't show and the `Print` isn't showing the values. Not sure about the precise value i should be using for `i` (which should represent all the candles for the current day) so I used 30 for now.

Comment: if you use `printf()` - read the instructions first. alternatively use `Print` and put all what you need by separating with comma, up to 64 elements. `iTime(_Symbol,60,i)` will give you time (e.g. now 23.11.2018 10:00 and `iTime` will return `1542967200` so it is always >1`. You were suggested to use `TimeHour()` and do not use it so far

Answer (score 0):

This is super lazy and I don't have time to give context, but you can set a break point and step through this example in the debugger.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         Tops.mq4 |
//|                                                      nicholishen |
//|                         https://www.forexfactory.com/nicholishen |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "nicholishen"
#property link      "https://www.forexfactory.com/nicholishen"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window
#include <arrays/list.mqh>
#include <chartobjects/chartobjectslines.mqh>

class Line : public CChartObjectTrend
{
   static int  m_instances;
   int         m_instance;
 public:
   Line(datetime t1, double p1, datetime t2, double p2){ 
      m_instance = ++m_instances; 
      this.Create(0, "Line_"+string(m_instance), 0, t1, p1, t2, p2);
      this.Color(clrMagenta);
      this.RayRight(false);
   }
};
int Line::m_instances = 0;

CList list;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit(){return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
   if(list.Total() > 0)
      return(rates_total);
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      list.Add(new Line(time[i+1], high[i+1], time[i], high[i]));
   }
   return rates_total;
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```